# Realm Iterator Exception for method iterator.next()

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a Realm Object called Person which contains a reference to a List, where Dog is another Realm Object.

In order to traverse this list of dogs, I store an iterator using the following code (iterator and currentDog are defined within the ViewController)

```
iterator = selectedPerson.dogs.makeIterator() // dogs: List<Dog>
currentDog = iterator.next()
```

This performs works as necessary.

However, when trying to update currentDog from another function using the following code, I end up with an exception thrown by the RLMIterator class: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
if currentDogNumber < selectedPerson.dogs.count {
    currentDog = iterator.next()
}
```

UPDATE:

I no longer receive any errors if I change the second code snippet to the following rather crude code snippet:

```
if currentDogNumber < selectedPerson.dogs.count {
    iterator = selectedPerson.dogs.makeIterator()
    for _ in 0...currentDogNumber {
        currentDog = interval.next()
    }
}
```

Could this be due to the methods being executed on separate threads? 
And if so, how do I ensure that they are executed by the same thread

Comment: Where is this code? Are you inside a transaction?

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? Are you moving `iterator` between threads or queues?

Comment: Also, why are you assigning the return value of the iterator, which is presumably a `Dog`, to a variable that looks like it holds a number?

Comment: @AustinZ Sorry that was a typo, fixed now, and Realm 3.0.1 I think. I don't believe I am, I'm trying to change dog after I have shown the information to the user

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The first set of code is in a function called startSlideshow(), and the second piece of code is inside a function called updateSlideshow()

Comment: Does `updateSlideshow()` call `realm.write(() =>`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, I am not interacting with a database, but instead Realm Objects stored locally- I just want to traverse the list of Dog objects, simply displaying and not editing the data

Comment: Is there any chance that the `dogs` have been changed by a background thread after you stored the iterator?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Running the application again shows that the two methods are being executed on different threads. Is this likely to cause the issues I am experiencing??

Comment: Yes! Realm is not thread safe you should always fetch again from realm before doing anything. And if you are passing realm objects to store as properties for example, stop doing that and start passing Id's or other things and implementing getters for the objects.

Comment: Realm _objects_ are not safe to pass between threads. Realm itself is fully thread safe as long as you follow our threading guidelines (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading).